# PHP - $_POST - Stops working after IF?

Tags: php, http-post

I am passing a value through a form submission and then echo'ing the result (`echo $_POST["value"];`) onto the page in multiple places as a "test."

As I am doing this, I noticed that after my IF statement, the `$_POST["value"]` stops returning its value and I believe it is returning NULL.

The IF statement checks to see if the `$_POST["value"] = NULL`

Any reason for this?

Does $_POST only work once (or a limited number of times) before its "used up" or is there some other function that clears this value?

Comment: Show the code where this happens

Comment: please post the relevant code.

Comment: wow we have some answers even without seeing the code !!

Comment: looks like all these people found answers without the code. thanks all.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is because you are using `=` insted of `==`

`=` Sets the variable value.

`==` Check if it value is equal to another value.

Answer (score 1):

This is Wrong way of checking NULL values.Use [isset](http://www.php.net/isset) or [empty](http://www.php.net/empty) instead

**isset** — *Determine if a variable is set and is not NULL*

```
if(isset($_POST["value"])){

}
```

OR

**empty** — *Determine whether a variable is empty*

```
if(empty($_POST["value"])){
//Do what ever 

}
```

Comment: thanks for the alternative. doesnt quite "fix" my issue as well as the other answer since my issue was due to my own misunderstanding of comparison operators, as they corrected for me. Thanks

Comment: This would be the real answer for a real programmer

Comment: Using `$_POST["value"] = NULL` is extremely bad coding

Comment: So Make this as the answer :)

Comment: I was already planning on using one of those, eventually. and my question asks about the re-usability of `$_POST["value"]` and pointing out my flaw of accidentally assigning it as NULL answers my question in a more direct manner since it causes it to effectively be not re-usable. but u got a +1, Thanks =)

Answer (score 1):

its
`$_POST["value"] == NULL` not `$_POST["value"] = NULL`